# MYSQL: Add some data in the first row only based on group by ID

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, datatables, correlated-subquery

I have this set of sample data:

Table `invoice`:

```
--------------------------------------------------
| ID |     date     | invoice_number |   total   |
--------------------------------------------------
| 81 |  2017-03-24  |   0000000173   |  190.00   |
--------------------------------------------------
```

Table `invoice_addon`:

```
----------------------------------------------------------
| ID |  invoice_id  |       description       |  amount  |
----------------------------------------------------------
| 46 |      81      | Price Adjust. - Jumbo   |  -12.00  |
| 47 |      81      | Price Adjust. - Regular |  -12.00  |
----------------------------------------------------------
```

Table `orders`:

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| ID  |  invoice_id  |  box_name   |   size   |  price  |   tax   |  box_number  |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 177 |      81      | Jumbo Box   | 23x25x17 |  97.00  |  15.00  |  FCI107056   |
| 178 |      81      | Regular Box | 20x23x17 |  87.00  |  15.00  |  FCI107057   |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

What I want to achieve:

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| trans_date  | inv_number |  box_name   |   size   |  gross   |  box_number  | others | description                     |  net  |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 2017-03-24  | 0000000173 | Jumbo Box   | 23x25x17 |  112.00  |  FCI107056   | -24.00 |  Price Adjust. - Jumbo -12.00   | 88.00 |
|             |            |             |          |          |              |        |  Price Adjust. - Regular -12.00 |       |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 2017-03-24  | 0000000173 | Regular Box | 20x23x17 |  102.00  |  FCI107057   |      0 |  NULL                           | 102.00|
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

My current query:

```
SELECT DATE(i.date) AS trans_date, i.invoice_number AS inv_number, o.box_name as box_name, 
o.size AS size, (SELECT Price + Tax FROM orders WHERE ID = o.ID) AS gross, 
o.box_number AS box_number,
SUM(a.amount) AS others, 
(SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(description, ' ', amount) SEPARATOR '<br />') FROM invoice_addon WHERE invoice_id = i.ID) AS description, 
(SUM(o.price + o.tax) + SUM(a.amount)) AS net 
FROM `invoice` i 
INNER JOIN orders o ON i.ID = o.invoice_id 
LEFT JOIN invoice_addon a ON i.ID = a.invoice_id 
WHERE i.ID = 81
GROUP BY o.ID
```

The problem in the result in my query is, `others` and `description` columns are doubled. It should only be shown in the 1st row. No matter how many boxes are tied up in the invoice, they should only be added in the 1st row. The net also relies on those columns.

What I get:

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| trans_date  | inv_number |  box_name   |   size   |  gross   |  box_number  | others | description                     |  net   |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 2017-03-24  | 0000000173 | Jumbo Box   | 23x25x17 |  112.00  |  FCI107056   | -24.00 |  Price Adjust. - Jumbo -12.00   | 200.00 |
|             |            |             |          |          |              |        |  Price Adjust. - Regular -12.00 |        |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 2017-03-24  | 0000000173 | Regular Box | 20x23x17 |  102.00  |  FCI107057   | -24.00 |  Price Adjust. - Jumbo -12.00   | 180.00 |
|             |            |             |          |          |              |        |  Price Adjust. - Regular -12.00 |        |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Is it possible? How can I make it so?
(I'm doing this in MySQL using CodeIgniter and DataTable)

Comment: the main problem is that there is no Link for invoice_addon, so that a routine know to whoch box it relates. you shoulf redisn your approach

Comment: @nbk it doesn't matter as long as they get listed on the first data only. Always. Is the `invoice_id` being common to both `orders` table and `invoice_addon` not able to make this happen?

Comment: As you have no relation defined for invoice_addon.id so no alghorithm knows where it should add the invoice tax, so make ar relationship and everything goes easy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you need some `var` that can store current row number and check if it equal to `1`. Something like this:

```
SET @row_number = 0;
SELECT DATE(i.date) AS trans_date, i.invoice_number AS inv_number, o.box_name as box_name, 
o.size AS size, (SELECT Price + Tax FROM orders WHERE ID = o.ID) AS gross, 
o.box_number AS box_number,
if((@row_number:=@row_number + 1)=1,SUM(a.amount), null) AS others, 
if(@row_number=1,(SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(description, ' ', amount) 
SEPARATOR '<br />') FROM invoice_addon WHERE invoice_id = i.ID), null) AS description, 
(SUM(o.price + o.tax) + SUM(a.amount)) AS net 
FROM `invoice` i 
INNER JOIN orders o ON i.ID = o.invoice_id 
LEFT JOIN invoice_addon a ON i.ID = a.invoice_id  
WHERE i.ID = 81
GROUP BY o.ID
```

Comment: Evgeny thanks for your answer. It's working for specific data (`i.ID = 81`) but I'd like to use it without the `where` clause so the others and description should be filled in every new `invoice_id` comes up.

Comment: @elimariaaa that was not obvious from your question

Comment: @elimariaaa store last invoice_id in some var and check if is equal to the new one

Comment: Evgeny yes, sorry. Thanks!